# In Strapi V4, How should I register a middleware to alter the responses returned by /user or /user/:id?

Tags: middleware, strapi

I've started to play with middlewares, it's great !

Here's an example of how I can inject a middleware when calling endpoints `/api/playlists` or `/api/playlists/:id` (I edited the file `src/api/playlist/routes/playlist.js`).

```
module.exports = createCoreRouter('api::playlist.playlist', {
 config: {
   find: {
     middlewares: ['api::playlist.playlist.find']
   },
   findOne: {
     middlewares: ['api::playlist.playlist.find-one']
   },
 },
})
```

Of course, I also created my middlewares in `src/api/playlist/middlewares/find.js` and `src/api/playlist/middlewares/find-one.js`)

But know, I want to add another middleware to update the responses returned by the API when calling `/api/users` or `/api/users/:id`.

Since there is no directory `src/api/user` in the filetree, how should I register a middleware for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out :

1. create the file `src/extensions/user-permissions/strapi-server.js`

This is mine. It registers a middleware for each of those endpoints:

- GET /users/me : plugin::spiff-api.user-me
- GET /users : plugin::spiff-api.user-find
- GET /users/:id : plugin::spiff-api.user-find-one

  ```
  ("use strict");

  module.exports = (plugin) => {
    //if you see this, the configuration do loads:
    console.log("Custom strapi-server.js for user-permissions");

    //get api routes for 'user-permissions'
    const apiRoutes = plugin.routes['content-api'].routes;

    //add middleware for GET /users/me
    apiRoutes
      .filter(route => route.handler === 'user.me')
      .map(route => {
        route.config.middlewares = [
          ...(route.config.middlewares || []),
          'plugin::spiff-api.user-me'//middleware name
        ];
        return route;
      });

      //add middleware for GET /users/:id
      apiRoutes
        .filter(route => route.handler === 'user.findOne')
        .map(route => {
          route.config.middlewares = [
            ...(route.config.middlewares || []),
            'plugin::spiff-api.user-find-one'//middleware name
          ];
          return route;
        });

    //add middleware for GET /users
    apiRoutes
      .filter(route => route.handler === 'user.find')
      .map(route => {
        console.log(route)
        route.config.middlewares = [
          ...(route.config.middlewares || []),
          'plugin::spiff-api.user-find'//middleware name
        ];
        return route;
      });

  return plugin;
  };
  ```

Then, create your middlewares [middleware](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/middlewares), eg.

```
    export default (config, { strapi })=> {
      return async (ctx, next) => {
        console.info("running middleware 'user-find-one.js'");
        console.log();

        //update your query here if needed
        //eg. populate 'favoritePosts'
        ctx.query.populate = {
          ...ctx.query.populate ?? {},
          favoritePosts: {}
        }

        const controller = strapi.plugin('users-permissions').controller('user');
        await controller.findOne(ctx);//this populates ctx.body
        const response = ctx.body;

        //update your response here if needed

        ctx.body = response;
        
        await next();//not sure why this stands for

      }
    }
```

Comment: Great solution! Is that possible to create middleware inside extention-folder/middlewares/yourMiddleware.js and use it like plugin::extention-folder.yourMiddleware?